# Product of 1-100(One to Hundred)?

Tags: calculus

Question>>Find the Product of 1-100(One to Hundred)?

any formula for this situation,Please suggest me....

Comment: The result is $100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000$

Answer (score 3):

Well if you search for a short notation it is the same as 
$$100!$$ 
which is the same as

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

If you don't need the exact result things like stirlings formula will help you for an approximate result

With Stirlingsformula 
$$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n } \cdot \frac{n^n}{\exp(n)}$$
you get 
$$100! \approx 9.32485\cdot 10^{157}$$

The absolute error is 
$$100! - \sqrt{2\pi n } \cdot \frac{n^n}{\exp(n)} = 7.77392\cdot 10^{154}$$
which doesn't look that good, but the relative error
$$\frac{100!-\sqrt{2\pi n } \cdot \frac{n^n}{\exp(n)}}{100!}= 0.0008329$$ 
which is acceptable I guess

Answer (score 2):

This is usually written as $100!$, it is called 100 factorial, and it stands for $1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4\cdots \cdot 99 \cdot 100$. You can read more about $100!$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100!). Generally, there is no closed form for factorials but there are good formulas for approximating $n!$ even for very large values of $n$. You can read about [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for more information.

Comment: Isn't $100!$ a closed form?